# How to express cycle notation with a cyclic group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have the following permutation

$b=(2,4,7)(5,8,9)(1,3,6,10)$

How can I compute $<b>$ in this case? I can find the order of $b$ but what does that imply?

Help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found the order of $b$ to be 4. What does that imply tho, I do not know @user26857

Comment: The order is not $4$. Is $b^4(2)=2$?

Comment: Then I do not know how to compute it correctly. Can you please show how? @ThomasAndrews

Answer (score 1):

The task is to compute the subgroup of the symmetric group $S_{10}$ generated by the permutation $b$.

In general for two elements $g,h$ of a group $G$ we have $(gh)^n=g^nh^n$ provided $gh=hg$. The same holds for any product of a finite number of commuting group elements.

The permutation $b$ is given as the product of 3 cyclic permutations $g_1,g_2,g_3$ each one moving a subset of numbers disjoint from the subsets moved by the others. It is easy to see that therefore the 3 permutations commute: $g_1g_2g_3=g_1g_3g_2=g_3g_1g_2=\ldots$. Hence $(g_1g_2g_3)^n=g_1^ng_2^ng_3^n$.

Now $g_1$ and $g_2$ are of order $3$ while $g_3$ is of order $4$. Therefore the order of $b=g_1g_2g_3$ is the least common multiple of $3$ and $4$, which is $12$.

Consequently $\langle b\rangle=\{b^k : k=0,\ldots,11\}$. The various powers of $b$ are easy to compute using the fact that powers of cyclic permutations are easy to compute. For example:

$b^8=g_1^8g_2^8g_3^8=g_1^2g_2^2=(2 7 4)(5 9 8)$.

Answer (score 0):

To compute the cyclic subgroup generated by $b$, just compute the powers of $b$ until you reach the identity permutation.

Comment: I find that when $b$ is increased to the fourth power, one gets an identity permutation. But what is the use of it for finding $<b>$?

Comment: If you find $b^{4}$ to be the identity, then you are making a mistake: for example $(2,4,7)^{4} = (2,4,7)$.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I found it to be $12$ now. Is it true? If it is, how to use that fact?

Comment: It is true, as explained in my more general answer above. How to use it? If an element $x \in G$ hs order $m$, this means precisely that $\langle x \rangle = \{1_{G},x,x^{2},\ldots,x^{m-1} \}$.

Answer (score 0):

If a permutation $c$ is expressed as a product of disjoint cycles $c_{1},c_{2}\ldots,c_{k}$, of respective lengths $a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{k}$, then you can check that for any positive integer $j$, we have $c^{j} = c_{1}^{j}\ldots c_{k}^{j}$, and this is the identity if and only if each of $c_{1}^{j}, c_{2}^{j},\ldots,c_{k}^{j}$ is the identity. You should be able to verify from this that the order of $c$ is 
${\rm lcm}(a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{k})$.